# ¿Tener 5 intentos?

Tags: python, python-3.7, ejecutar

Me ayudan tengo que hacer que mi código solo tenga 5 intentos al poner una letra para divinar una frase y si se equivoca 5 veces aparezca que ya no tiene más intentos permitido y el puntaje total, pero si acierta letras (no se permiten números) ir dándole 10 puntos mostrándole de mensaje y al final decir el total con el que termina de puntaje si acierta con un mensaje de felicitaciones.

```py
    def run():
    frases = ["Vive tu momento",
              "Nunca subestimes el poder de la musica",
              "Nunca olvides lo mucho que tu familia te ama",
              "Porque la muerte es vida; enciende luces en otro lugar"]
    cantidad = len (frases)
    print(cantidad)
    numero = 0

    while numero < 1 or numero > cantidad:
        numero = int(input("Ingrese el numero de frase que desea revelar (1 al {c}): ".format(c=cantidad)))


    frase = frases [numero - 1]
    print(frase)
    patron = ""
    for i in frase:
        if i == " ":
            patron += " "
        else:
            patron += "_"
    patron = list(patron)
    presentar(patron)

    while True:
        letra = input("Ingrese letra: ")
        x = 0
        for i in frase:
            if letra.lower() == i.lower():
                patron[x] = letra
            x+=1
        if "_" not in patron:
            break
        presentar(patron)
    presentar(patron)

    def presentar(patron):
    p=""
    for i in patron:
        p = p + i
    print(p)


    if __name__=="__main__":
    run()
```

Comment: Cambiar el while, que revise alguna variable booleana (true|false) y validas en cada iteración del while un contador, ves si ya está en 5 y te sales del while; si el usuario acierta letra, le vas sumando puntos; si falla, le sumas uno al contador de fallos y listo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simpre, Creando un contador:

```python
count=0;
while True:
        letra = input("Ingrese letra: ")
        if letra.lower() in frase.lower():#Si la letra esta en la cadena entonces usamos el bucle para obtener la letra.
            for i in frase:
                if letra.lower() == i.lower():
                    patron[x] = letra
        else:#sino aumentamos el patron y vemos si perdió.
            count+=1;
            if count>=5:#Vemos si perdió.
                print("You Loser.;)");
                    break;
        if "_" not in patron:
            break
        presentar(patron)
```

Mis cambios fueron:

```python
count=0;
...
    if letra.lower() in frase.lower():#Si la letra esta en la cadena entonces usamos el bucle para obtener la letra.
        for i in frase:
            ...
    else:#Sino complovamos si perdió.
        count+=1;
        if count>=5:
            print("You lose.;)");
            break;
...
```

La primera línea se inicializa la variable `count` a 0 para ir aumentándolo(Pero si quieres llamarla `life` y colócale en 5 para ir disminuyéndola cada vez que falle y comprobar si no es 0 o menor: `if not life<=0:`), la segunda línea que cambie sera la que nos indique si la letra esta en la frase(Si lo esta recorremos el bucle) sino hacemos lo que queremos para comprobar y ver si perdió el jugador.

Una Observación: La función presentar no creo que tenga mucho sentido, porque siempre mostrará la ultima letra de la frase recogida por el jugador:

```python
for i in patron:
    #p=i;#Siempre sobre escribimos p, por lo que cuando llegue a print siempre enseñará la ultima letra.
    p+=i;#Por lo que debemos concatenar la cadena, en python ofrese una forma muy facil: str_+str_: p=p+i o p+=i;
print(p);#Para que al llegar aqui muetre todas las letras.
```

Comment: Estuve tratando de ponerlo en el código pero me arroja error

Answer (score 0):

Creo es algo simple de comprender. Tu `while` debe validar que los intentos restantes sean mayor 0.

En algun lugar de tu codigo(antes del `while`) inicializas los intentos restantes que va a tener.

```
intentos_restantes = 5 # dices que inicia con cinco intentos
```

ahora en el `while` haces la validacion de que tenga intentos disponibles:

```
while intentos_restantes > 0:
    # aqui va el resto de tu codigo
```

En algun lugar de tu codigo, cuando quieras quitarle un intento, solo le restas 1 a `intentos_restantes`. Por supuesto dentro del `while`.

```
# en esta parte del codigo le quitas un intento
intentos_restantes = intentos_restantes - 1
```

Y listo, cuando `intentos_restantes` sea 0 ya no podra continuar el `while`.

Si quieres salir del `while` sin importar la condicion puedes usar `break`.